GetFromJsonAsync --> Failed to fetch with blazor and WASM
У меня есть апи метод который спрашивает у бд есть у нее такой-то мейл. Апи прекрасно взаимодействуют друг с другом
 [HttpGet]
 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("IsEmailExist")]
 public async Task<bool> IsEmailExist(string email) {

     using HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
     var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<bool>("https://localhost:7282/User/IsEmailExist?email=" + email);
     return response;

 }
 


Когда я хочу сделать то же самое из проекта blazor webasm
    public async Task<bool> IsEmailExist(string email)
    {
        using HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
       try
        {
            var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<bool>("https://localhost:5059/Users/IsEmailExist?email=" + email);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("Error check email: {Error}", ex);
        }

        return false;
    
    }

Вылезает ошибкаFailed to fetch! Cores any enabled

использовать http вместо https помогло мне. Но это временное решение
